# Problem when same lat lon are passed on mkmapview

Tags: iphone, xcode, mkmapview

I am having a mkmpaview in which i show different annotations based on address .I dont get any problem whne all the alat lon are different , but whenever i pass the same lat lon pair then instead of showing two annotations like google maps it shows only one pin .

My scenario is like say i have array of lat lon which is pass for adding annotations , the problem occurs when two pair of lat lon are same if three pair are same then also it shows only 1 pin for the 3.

IF someone has came across the same problem , please help me with that solution .
Any suggestions for different approaches would be accepted .

Hope i am clear with my question.

Comment: Are sure it is adding only one pin? What you see may be three pins overlaying one another, so you would only see the top pin if they are identical. If you change the images of each pin (as a test), you might be able see that there are, indeed, multiple annotation images when you expect them. MKMapView does not display multiple pins the same way Google Maps and Google Earth do when they coincide with one another.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but i will try to interpret what exactly you are asking.

I believe you want to use different annotation images , for the annotations you are adding that have the same longitude and latitude.

The approach isn't very clear, what exactly is the point of adding multiple annotations with different images in the same location?

You could load the annotations more than once, with different images, but i don't think this would have much sense.

You could also assign tags to the annotation images, and call both tags when loading the annotations on map view.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question is very simple!

1) First detect each "same" latitude and longitudes.

2) When inserting pin to that particular location (latitude and longitude) use different color pin.

3) When tapping on pin, check the location of pin and if that belongs to one of the locations that we previously identified, write code appropriately to notify user.

Suppose you are displaying address on a label(on annotation view) when tapped on pin. And when you tapped on pin where there are more than one location assigned, try to display addresses on a scroll view so user can determine all the addresses. This way use some simple logic to tackle the situation.